# Opening file to read structure array

Tags: c++, file, input, structure

I'm a beginner in computer science learning c++.

Every attempt that I make to open a file in my program and read the information into a structure does not work.

Here is what I have written in the function.

```
void getMemberInfo(Payment member[])
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("information.txt", ios::in);
    int i = 0;

    if (!file)
       cout << "\n Error opening file!\n\n";

    else
    {
        while (!file)
        {
            file >> member[i].ID;
            file.getline(member[i].name, 30, '\n');
            member[i].member_name = member[i].name;
            file >> member[i].payment_due;
            i++;

            if (file.eof())
            break;
    }
}

file.close();
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm kind of at a loss of what's wrong.

Comment: Probably the file is not in your current working directory.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger to determine where the program is going wrong.  Edit your post with the results of using a debugger.

Comment: Please edit your post with a sample of the input data file.

Comment: The usual reading idiom is: `while (file >> member[i].ID)`

Comment: Post sample file that you are trying to read and your Payment class

Comment: Show the definition of `Payment` and the structure of the input data in the file.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I change the while(!file) to while(file) and it works. I'm making simple mistakes. Still, thanks for the quick answers.

Comment: It _appears_ to work - read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong  and https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/

Answer (score -3):

The error is in the while condition. Just change the condition and it should work

```
// Instead of !file, use !file.eof()
while (!file.eof())
```

Comment: Better it should be `while (file)`

Comment: I think i've been looking at the screen for so long i missed it

Comment: No. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong?noredirect=1&lq=1